# How to use 'EXPLAIN SELECT' in Zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, orm

I use bellow query to count rows in zend framework:

```
SELECT
  count(id)
FROM
  adt
WHERE
  timeStamp > $time
```

It has so many rows under this condition and It took 7 minute to fetch result. I searched and i found that i can use EXPLAIN SELECT instead of this query. I want to change query to:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
  count(id)
FROM
  adt
WHERE
  timeStamp > $time
```

How can i make this query using zend DB?

Comment: Just do your EXPLAIN from the database command line (editing in a $time value).... it will almost certainly tell you that it's doing a full table scan because you don't have an index on the `timeStamp` column in your table

Comment: I want to use it in zend not mysql command line. It is for count of paginator.

Comment: The __query__ is for count of paginator. The __EXPLAIN__ is to tell you how the query executes.... EXPLAIN will return a query execution plan, EXPLAIN will not return the count for pagination.... UNDERSTAND YOUR TOOLS